# Loop Json array with gson

Tags: java, json

Im trying to parse a jsonObject and can't seem to get it, here is what i got.

```
 json = (json data)
 JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
 JsonObject rootObj = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
 JsonObject paymentsObject = rootObj.getAsJsonObject("payments");

 for(JsonObject pa : paymentsObject){
        String dateEntered = pa.getAsJsonObject().get("date_entered").toString();
    }
```

But i get a foreach not applicable to type what am i missing. I've tried different ways but can't seem to get it. thanks

Json

```
 {
 "Name":"Test 2",
 "amountCollected":"1997",
 "payments":[
  {
     "quoteid":"96a064b9-3437-d536-fe12-56a9caf5d881",
     "date_entered":"2016-05-06 08:33:48",
     "amount":"1962",         
  },
  {
     "quoteid":"96a064b9-3437-d536-fe12-56a9caf5d881",
     "date_entered":"2016-05-06 08:33:08",
     "amount":"15",         
  },
  {
     "quoteid":"96a064b9-3437-d536-fe12-56a9caf5d881",
     "date_entered":"2016-05-06 03:19:08",
     "amount":"20",         
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: `JsonObject` is not `Iterable`, so you cannot use it in an enhanced `for` loop like that. Maybe if you shared an example of the Json data you're trying to parse, we can better help you. One thought though: Are you sure the value of `payments` is an object, and not an array? Maybe you should have called `rootObj.getAsJsonArray("payments")`. The returned `JsonArray` *is* iterable.

Comment: I tried that and i get a com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonArray

Comment: updated question, thanks

Comment: Looks like you forgot to [`json_encode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) that PHP class.

Comment: thats just the output from php updated with raw json

Comment: Since you are using Gson, you shouldn't need to manually parse the JSON. You might want to use this site to make some Java objects that Gson can use. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Now that we can see the data, we can see that `payments` *is* in fact an array (values uses `[]`).

That means you need to call `rootObj.getAsJsonArray("payments")` which returns a `JsonArray`, and it is an `Iterable<JsonElement>`, which means your loop should be `for(JsonElement pa : paymentsObject)`.

Remember, each value of the array can be any type of Json element (object, array, string, number, ...).

You know that they are `JsonObject`, so you can call `getAsJsonObject()` on them.

```
json = (json data)
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject rootObj = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray paymentsArray = rootObj.getAsJsonArray("payments");
for (JsonElement pa : paymentsArray) {
    JsonObject paymentObj = pa.getAsJsonObject();
    String     quoteid     = paymentObj.get("quoteid").getAsString();
    String     dateEntered = paymentObj.get("date_entered").getAsString();
    BigDecimal amount      = paymentObj.get("amount").getAsBigDecimal();
}
```

Comment: you are correct, i just noticed that sometimes my payments when a single value is a object not a array which is causing the error. Thanks you all for your help.